Ubuntu24.04: Python application not working due to missing libffi.so.7
I just upgraded my workstation to 24.04 and the key application I am working on is not working anymore.
I have the same error: libffi.so.7 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have tried both on Python3.7 and 3.9
As per the question:libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
I have also tried to re-install libffi.so.2, but apt complains that there is no compatible version.
Moving backward to 22.01 looks complicated.
Any solution ?

AFAIK Ubuntu 24.04 uses libffi.so.8 (package libffi8) (not to mention python3.12) so probably the application should be updated to use those versions

This question is similar to: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To ensure compatibility for deployment, all development are still using Python3.7. I woill test the upgraded 3.12 version.
